# Android listview with onclickitems

Tags: listview, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

Hello am a new programmer and **I've been trying to make an app like a book with lisview and when you click on it takes you to another activity.**
I tried googling the codes but couldn't find the right one.
I have a list names of a topic and when i click on it i want it to take me to the other activity, i stored all the properties of the topic name and thr content in thr string file.
So when i click on it i want it to take me to the view text activity and get the properties from thr strings and change the texy every time i click on a item

Answer (score 0):

```
listviewObj..setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //do here what you want
    }
});
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.